# Using a mock implementation as an argument for a function expecting an interface

Tags: go

In my go application, I have a MyClient struct and a MyClients struct which holds a map of MyClient. The idea is that depending on your needs you can request a specific client by a key.

For testing, I created a mock version which as far as I can tell should satisfy all of the interfaces I declared. However, Go doesn't like that my mock implementation of the Client method returns a MockClient (which satisfies the MyClient interface) instead of a MyClient.

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong, or why this doesn't work. I'm missing something obvious I feel.

client.go

```
type ClientProvider interface {
    Client(model string) MyClient
}

type MyClients struct {
    Clients map[string]MyClient
}

func (mc *MyClients) Client(client string) MyClient {
    return mc.Clients[client]
}

type MyClient interface {
    Get()
}
```

client_mock.go

```
type MyClientsMock struct {
    Clients map[string]MyClientMock
}

func (mcm *MyClientsMock) Client(client string) MyClientMock {
    println("I an satisfying the ClientProvider Interface")
    return mcm.Clients[client]
}

type MyClientMock struct {
    MyClient
    Response string
    Err      error
}

func (mcm MyClientMock) Get() {
    println("I an satisfying the MyClient Interface")
}

func NewMyClientsMock() MyClientsMock {
    return MyClientsMock{
        Clients: map[string]MyClientMock{
            "client-a": {Response: "hello from client a"},
            "client-b": {Response: "hello from client b"},
        },
    }
}
```

main.go

```
func main() {
    myClientsMock := NewMyClientsMock()

    // WHY CAN'T I DO THIS
    test(myClientsMock)
}

func test(clients ClientProvider) {

}
```

Comment: Why are the MyClient and MyClientMock not the same if they both have the Get method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Go doesn't like that my mock implementation of the Client method returns a MockClient (which satisfies the MyClient interface) instead of a MyClient.

It's totally fine for the method to return a MyClientMock (since any MyClientMock is a MyClient), but its declared return-type needs to be MyClient in order to satisfy the interface:

```
func (mcm *MyClientsMock) Client(client string) MyClient {
    println("I an satisfying the ClientProvider Interface")
    return mcm.Clients[client]
}
```

Comment: Are you getting this error when copy-paste code from OP? `/prog.go:51:7: cannot use myClientsMock (variable of type MyClientsMock) as ClientProvider value in argument to test: MyClientsMock does not implement ClientProvider (method Client has pointer receiver)`

Comment: @MilosStojanovic: That doesn't seem to be what the OP is concerned about, but FWIW, it can be addressed with a well-placed ampersand.

Comment: I see, I was hoping the return type implementing the interface would be enough. Thanks for the answer. The interface and tests are in the same package and my mock in another, which causes circular dependencies if used this way. I guess a rethink of package structure is order.